# Using a background image on css hosted on imgur

Tags: css, image, background, hosting, imgur

I am having difficulty in making my hosted background image show up on a webpage portfolio for my school assignment. I would be more than happy to provide more information. Thank you.

Here is a screenshot of the code:

[image: Background image code]

Comment: Please add your code as text format !

Comment: @Wolf_NH: What is your problem? Please add your code as text.

Comment: **USE** `background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ltmp.png")` **DONT** `background: #hex url(...)`

Comment: body {
  background: #dcdfe2 url("https://i.imgur.com/2NXVCnd.jpg/ ");
  color: #808080;
  font: normal 14px/20px 'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }

Comment: you have `/` in the url at the start, remove it

Answer (score 3):

Remove slash before the image link.

Invalid:

```
background: url("/https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ltmp.png")
```

Valid:

```
background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ltmp.png")
```